# Extracting data from keys in JSON Object

Tags: java, json, spring-boot

I am getting a response such as

```js
[
   
      {
         "externalId1":"NULL",
         "externalId2":"NULL"
      }
   ,
   
      {
         "externalId1":"NULL",
         "externalId2":"NULL"
      }
   
]
```

and this response is stored in a `List<String>` variable name `response1`.

I want to extract the value of externalId1 and externalId2 and store it in a List

The code which I wrote is below:

//response1 is the list in which the array of response is being stored, and the array of response is already written above.

However after doing this the exception comes as it is not a JSONObject. The loop doesn't extract the required data. Ideally the values of both the keys externalId1 and externalId2 should have been printed. But the loop keeps giving exception and hence says "NOT JSONObject".

```
List<String> response1 = new ArrayList<String>();
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response1);

for (int i=0; i<array.length(); i++)
{
  JSONObject object = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
  System.out.println(object.getString("externalId1");
  System.out.println(object.getString("externalId2");
}
```

Edit:I have modified the response which I got by making code changes in my machine after feedback from few users on stackoverflow.

Comment: You have an **array of array** in your JSON example.

Comment: In JSON: `[ ]` represents list/array, `{ }` represents object. Structure like `[ [ { } ] ]` it is  array containing array containing object. I am not sure where did you get `List<String>` from..

Comment: Yes the response came from a database and I stored the cumulative response in a string list , now i need to extract the data for each of the keys

Comment: Just add en extra operation to get the inner array first and then extract the object in it

Comment: Thanks Gael J , I have now modified the response itself now it is a single array with objects and it is stored in a type List<String> , I then did the same code which is in the description yet I am unable to extract the info

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion,
the best way is you have to implement the DTO class. For example:

```
public class ExternalId {
   private String externalId1;
   private String externalId2;
}

@PostMapping("/test")
public void parseJsonExample(@RequestBody List<List<ExternalId>> requestBody) {
  //do whatever you want on your list objects
}
```

Comment: Need to do without DTO but because I have to migrate the key values to another location where I will frame a new response.